# Java Pattern Matching: First Level of Parantheses

Tags: java, regex

I want to use Java Pattern matching to split a string so that I get the content in the first level of parantheses.
For example for the string

```
address={country={iso=ITA&name=italy}}&category={name=demo&tags={tag1=value1&tag2=value2}}
```

I want to get

`country={iso=ITA&name=italy}` and `name=demo&tags={tag1=value1&tag2=value2}`

Is this possible with Java regex pattern matching (groups/lookahead?) or do I have to track the parantheses level "manually"?

Comment: No you cannot match a nesting structure with finite automata, which regexes are.

Comment: IMO you should write your own parser which will count parentheses. It may be possible to also solve it with regex (depending on form of your input) but I suspect that it will not be easy task and if your requirement will change (for instance increased unlimited nesting level) maintaining such regex will be nightmare.

Comment: These things (objects?) look so much like JSON, but yet not.  If you have control over the generation of these, try going the JSON route and use the Jackson library.

Comment: Then my first intuition obviously was correct that this requires a context-free grammar approach ;-) Thanks for verifying that.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
String str = "address={country={iso=ITA&name=italy}}&category={name=demo&tags={tag1=value1&tag2=value2}}";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.+?)\\}\\}");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
            while(m.find())
                System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Yields:

```
country={iso=ITA&name=italy
name=demo&tags={tag1=value1&tag2=value2
```